# Is it possible to determine the size of a type from the types of its data members

Tags: c++, sizeof, type-traits, memory-alignment, stdtuple

**Problem:**

Consider the following type:

```cpp
struct S {
    std::uint8_t a;
    std::uint32_t b;
};
```

Is it possible to determine `sizeof(S)` from `std::uint8_t` and `std::uint32_t` solely?

**Context:**

I'm developing a code where `S` is actually a template type more verbose than this illustration-purpose one, so I thought in defining a traits class for generically determining the size of a type from the types of its data members. So far, I had two ideas:

1. Using alignment of data members

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
inline constexpr std::size_t aligned_sizeof_all_v = sizeof...(Ts) * std::max(alignof(Ts)...);
```

2. Using `std::tuple`

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
inline constexpr std::size_t aligned_sizeof_all_v = sizeof(std::tuple<Ts...>);
```

Using both approaches seem to succeed, although I'm reluctant about the second one since the implementation of `std::tuple` provides no guarantees with respect to its size:

```cpp
static_assert(aligned_sizeof_all_v<std::uint8_t, std::uint32_t> == sizeof(S));
```

Is this a correct way of determining a type's size?

Comment: Why do you need to determine the size of the class from it's members when you can just ask `sizeof` to give you the size of the class?  There is no way other than that to *know* the size of the class.

Comment: As I said, it's a template class. It's totally possible to determine the size of the template class but it's deducing a function signature, you know, splitting return type from argument types and stuff. I guess you'd have to see the code to understand it. So I thought of using a different approach. If there's no other approach, fine, but I think it's good to know about alternatives.

Comment: In generally there is no way for you to know what the size is going to be.  This is even more the case as soon as virtual functions are involved.  C++ already has a lot of stuff about function deduction so you might be better of asking about that.

Comment: Try `struct S { uint8_t a, b; std::uint32_t c; };` with your `aligned_sizeof_all_v`. I think it will not provide the correct size.

Comment: Virtual functions are not involved here, but aight, gonna take your comment for an answer then. Thanks.

Comment: The size of a class or struct is not just the size of its members always. The compiler may insert padding bytes between members to align them on specific address boundaries.

Comment: @DanielLangr It works here, although you have to change it to `aligned_sizeof_all_v<std::uint8_t, std::uint8_t, std::uint32_t> == sizeof(S)`, naturally.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know, that's why the first version of the traits class is based on `alignof`.

Comment: @SepiaColor It doesn't work for me: https://godbolt.org/z/S3wjkz. Or, I don't understand your problem correctly. The problem I see in this context is that `aligned_sizeof_all_v` is "symmetric", while the size of a struct may depend on the order of its members.

Comment: @DanielLangr Oh, yeah, you're right, now I see the logical flaw

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member

Comment: @idclev463035818 Kind of. Wrt my question, that answer you linked only shows approach 1 is flawed, though. There's still approach 2. But anyways, I'm not having a headache to find an alternative approach to `sizeof`.

Comment: even if you could know the size of the tuple for sure you dont know the size of `S`. Afaik there is no guarantee (packed attributes aside) for the size of a type. Nothing but common sense prevents the size of `S` to be 42 or 123

Comment: @idclev463035818 Corner cases aside, aren't layout-compatible types supposed to have the same size?

Comment: afaik layout-compatible is not guaranteed same size (cf https://stackoverflow.com/q/53041630/4117728). Its something I'd expect but not rely on

Comment: actually i dont get your use case. Whats wrong with `sizeof(S)` ?

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 It is so _obvious_ that layout-compatible types would have the same padding that it would follow they have the same size. I wonder if there's any valid reason for not providing a guarantee for this.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Think of my use case that of one who would prefer reading `some_type_modification_t<T>` rather than `typename some_type_modification<T>::type`.

Comment: I dont understand. You should explain the actual problem that you want to solve.

Comment: I can't make it clearer than that. If you're still confused, ask yourself why aliases exist, which "problems" they solve. I'm not sharing the original code; it's government top secret, sowwy.

Comment: i know why aliases exist, but I dont understand why you need an alias for `sizeof(S)`

Comment: Just want to add that you could also use a fold expression to sum the sizes of the types: `(sizeof(Ts) + ...)`. Pack your structs and it'll be accurate :)

Comment: The answer is 'no', because the class could have a separate `alignof` annotation, or virtual methods, or many other exceptions.  `struct alignas(8) S {};`

Comment: as said, this is likely the XY problem. If you just want to avoid the use of `typename` then [upgrade to C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61990971/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If the types and order of the object's members are known, and if all members have the same access specifier (e.g. `public`), *and* if the object lacks a vtable, you can rebuild the object's structure within a helper class and use the size of that:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct struct_traits {
    static constexpr std::size_t size() {
        return sizeof(struct_builder<Ts...>);
    }

private:
    template<typename First, typename... Rest>
    struct struct_builder : struct_builder<Rest...> {
        First v;
    };
    template<typename First>
    struct struct_builder<First> {
        First v;
    };

    // Below: addition to work with structures declared with alignas().
public:
    template<std::size_t alignas_>
    static constexpr std::size_t size() {
        return sizeof(aligned_struct_builder<alignas_, Ts...>);
    }

private:
    template<std::size_t alignas_, typename First, typename... Rest>
    struct alignas(alignas_) aligned_struct_builder : aligned_struct_builder<alignas_, Rest...> {
        First v;
    };
    template<std::size_t alignas_, typename First>
    struct alignas(alignas_) aligned_struct_builder<alignas_, First> {
        First v;
    };
};
```

Example of use (try it [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TxnGfg)):

```
struct S
{ 
    uint8_t a, b;
    uint32_t c;
};

static_assert(struct_traits<uint8_t, uint8_t, uint32_t>::size() == sizeof(S)); // True! 8 == 8
static_assert(struct_traits<uint8_t, uint32_t, uint8_t>::size() == sizeof(S)); // Bad: 12 != 8
```

Use against `alignas`-ed structure ([on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/f_cxDn)):

```
struct alignas(8) S
{ 
    uint8_t a;
    uint32_t c;
    uint8_t b;
};

static_assert(struct_traits<uint8_t, uint32_t, uint8_t>::size<8>(), sizeof(S)); // True: 16 == 16
```

Inspiration from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781417/declare-member-variables-from-variadic-template-parameter).

Comment: This assumes layout-compatible types have the same size. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62520731/is-it-possible-to-determine-the-size-of-a-type-from-the-types-of-its-data-member/62523297#comment110568686_62520731), it may not be guaranteed?

Comment: @SepiaColor: `struct_builder` isn't necessarily looking to be layout-compatible; I'd argue that this code instead relies on the compiler using the same alignment decisions for all structures. If the compiler pads the members of `struct A { char c; int n; };` the same way it does `struct B { char q; int x; };`, then A's and B's sizes are going to be the same. I'd say this assumption is safe to make.

Comment: [`struct alignas(8) S {virtual ~S(){}};` begs to differ](https://godbolt.org/z/zTPGTh)

Comment: @MooingDuck: A double whammy: Introducing a vtable will affect the struct's size, as well as using `alignas`. Could at least account for the latter by adding a non-type template parameter, updating my answer again.