# Data members from variadic typename template and overloading

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Similar to question [Declare member variables from variadic template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781417/declare-member-variables-from-variadic-template-parameter), but with an additional question:

Let's say I have 2 (or many) structs:

```
struct A { int a; };
struct B { int b; };
```

And I want to make a class holding dynamic arrays of each, AND be able to have a call doing specific processing to one of those types:

```
struct Manager<A, B>
{
    std::vector<A> as;
    std::vector<B> bs;
    template<typename T> process();
};
```

Where, if I call `process<A>` it will loop over all "as", and `process<B>` loops over all "bs".

Additionally, I provide A, B or any number of structs (distinct from eachother) as variadic template parameters. In other words, doing `Manager<A, B>` is the expected use, but doing `Manager<A, A, B>` is not allowed (because of the 2 'A's).

Is this possible (and, if possible, in a way that doesn't create a stupidly high amount of boilerplate code or is unreadeable)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, `std::tuple` does the job too:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct Manager
{
    std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> vectors;

    template <typename T, typename F>
    void process(F f) {
        for (auto& e : std::get<std::vector<T>>(vectors)) {
            f(e);
        }
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73d5d9fbaf846e4f)

Comment: Some traits are also needed to reject duplicate types.

Comment: @康桓瑋: `std::get<T>` would fail with duplicate. So it might be enough.

Comment: "*but doing Manager<A, A, B> is not allowed*", so I think OP wants to reject this situation when instantiating `Manager`.

Comment: Regarding Manager<A, A, B>, it's a given contract that the developer will never try that. However @Jarod42 I cannot manage to successfully implement the solution you've proposed, I get "error: no matching function for call to ‘get > >(std::tuple >, std::vector > >&)’", could you please provide a working example?

Comment: @ZeroZ30o: Demo added.

Comment: @Jarod42 ah thanks, the demo didn't work either: it was the online compiler's fault, must be an older version? (for reference, the online compiler is "onlinegdb"). On other compilers, everything works fine, thanks!

Comment: @ZeroZ30o: `std::get<T>` requires C++14, so make sure to set `-std=c++14` (or more recent version). [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/mFPuqf1Pt) with onlinegdb.

Comment: @ZeroZ30o FWIW, You can also use these online compilers: [1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/), [2](https://godbolt.org/), [3](https://wandbox.org/)

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't want to open another question, but - how would I make 1 array of ints per type given as variadic parameter? (this would store the id of each element in the vectors). So if I provide 2 types, A and B, it would make 2 "int" vectors (dynamic arrays) - how?

Comment: @Jarod42 or rather, I know how to find how many types are passed (with sizeof...(Ts)), but how can I get an index for each type? For example in Manager<A, B>, how can I obtain "0" if I call a function with A, and "1" if I call a function with B?

Comment: @ZeroZ30o: See [get-index-of-a-tuple-elements-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063451/get-index-of-a-tuple-elements-type).